# angular 2 cannot connect to server

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm working on Angular 2 and my back end is NodeJs. I just followed the tutorial to connect to the server but it does not work. This is my code in app.component.ts:

```
this.http.get<Contributor[]>('http://localhost:3000/message/').subscribe(data => {
            // data is now an instance of type ItemsResponse, so you can do this:
            this.contributors = data;
            console.log(this.contributors);
        });
        console.log(this.contributors);
```

the first "this.contributors" displays data well but the second one is undefined. Is there any could help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because javascript is asynchronous. after sending the HTTP request, angular does not wait until event subscribe. it just keeps on executing. that's why the second `console.log(this.contributors);` executes first and it's undefined. after subscribing to the event it shows the  `console.log` that inside the subscribe method with data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Is there anyway to deal with it, or just wait for it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: since http is asynchronous you have to wait for it

Comment: But my table read the contributors and return the undefined. Is there anyway to let all other things pause and just wait for the http? Or is there any synchronous call for it? Thanks!

Comment: wrap your other things around a function and call that function inside `subscribe`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map()` since it return the created Observable for the caller to subscribe.

so you can do this :

```
getData():any {
return this.http.get<Contributor[]>('http://localhost:3000/message/').map( 
    (response) => {
      this.contributors = response;
      console.log(this.contributors);
      return JSON.stringify(this.contributors);
    }
}
```

and then in your component subscript to it like :

```
this.getData().subscribe(data => {/* here you can access data */ 
   console.log(data);
});
```

make sure you import the map operator :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the Constant.areaList?

Comment: It was from my code, forgot to edit it with what you had, you can replace it with this.contributors